# R to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I got a data frame in R querying a SQL Server DB, Now I want to loop on each line and insert it to MySQL DB

Tried with dbwritetable but it didn't work

```
library(RODBC)
library(odbc)
library(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "XX",
                 Database = "XX",
                 UID = "XX",
                 PWD = "XX",
                 Port = XX)


mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='XX', password='XX', dbname='YY', host='YYY')


resultset <- dbGetQuery(con, "SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
SET @StartDate = dateadd(d,-1,getdate())
SET @EndDate = getdate()
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT …..
LEFT JOIN ... ON ….
LEFT JOIN …. ON x.Key = y.Key
WHERE temp.StartDateTime >= @StartDate")

nrows <- nrow(resultset)
colnames(resultset) <- c("tagName", "date_inserted","value") `
```

So in here I got my result, in resultset but I don't know how to insert the resulset in MySQL

```
    dbWriteTable(mydb, name='data', value=resultset[0,],append=TRUE)
```

dbReadTable(mydb, "data")

I Expect to insert the data, but I don't know should it be a for loop (for each line a query) or how is it done

More details with this images :

[This is my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwUhN.png)

[This is MySQL DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh49U.png)

Comment: So what does SQL Server tag do here? Is it relevant?

Comment: @sami Yes it is, I want to insert these 3 columns (tagName , data ,value) in MySQL DB which has the same structure (you can check it the 2nd picture)

Comment: MySQL isn't SQL Server they are different RDBMS.

Comment: Yeah, the `Driver = "SQL Server"` is probably wrong. Need the MySQL specific driver.

Comment: I got frustrated with RODBC and now use DBI for SQL Server queries.

Comment: `RODBC` has some advantages, but typically I use `odbc` and `DBI` now as well. I have difficulties with `odbc` and Microsoft Access, which unfortunately I find myself having to use. `RODBC` seems to consistently work better here.

Comment: I know it's not the same.
But I need 2 connections in here, the first one is to SQL Server DB to retrieve my dataset.

After That I need the connection to MySQL, so I can insert my dataset in MySQL

Comment: What is the problem with current `dbWriteTable` code? Post any errors that is raised. Note: `resultset[0,]` selects nothing as R is not zero-indexed and even if it is a positive non-zero number, you would be selecting that specific row only.

Comment: I tried with the function that Adam suggested and I am getting this error :
connot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'caracter'.

this is the function :  

saveTable <- function(con, table_name, df) {
  # con = the ODBC connection (e.g., ch)
  # table_name = the SQL database table to append to
  # df = the data.frame() to append

  sql_code = paste("INSERT INTO",table_name,"(",paste(colnames(df),collapse=", "),") VALUES (",paste(rep("?",ncol(df)),collapse=","),")")
  
  sqlExecute(con, sql_code, df)
}
saveTable(ch,data,resultset)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a *parameterized insert* using the `RODBCext` package. I have used the following function in the past.

This will append records into your database

```
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)
```

First we need to connect to the database using `RODBC`.

```
sql.driver  = "MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver" # need to figure the version out
sql.server  = "your_server_here"
sql.port    = "3306" # or whatever your port number is
sql.user    = "your_user_name_here"
sql.pass    = "your_password_name_here"
sql.db      = "your_database_name_here"

con.string = paste0("Driver=", sql.driver, ";",
                    "Server=", sql.server, ";",
                    "Port=", sql.port, ";",
                    "Uid=", sql.user, ";",
                    "Pwd=", sql.pass, ";",
                    "Database=", sql.db, ";")

ch = odbcDriverConnect(con.string)
```

Then here is the custom function `saveTable()`. You will want to run this with your specific inputs, defined below.

```
saveTable <- function(con, table_name, df) {
  # con = the ODBC connection (e.g., ch)
  # table_name = the SQL database table to append to
  # df = the data.frame() to append

  sql_code = paste("INSERT INTO",table_name,"(",paste(colnames(df),collapse=", "),") VALUES (",paste(rep("?",ncol(df)),collapse=","),")")

  sqlExecute(con, sql_code, df)
}
```